# For Geom Field Recalc is WHERE or INNER JOIN Preferred?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I've read through many of the posts discussing the merits of using INNER JOIN vs WHERE.  The explanations I am finding all seem to suggest that the preference for INNER JOIN has more to do with readability than functionality.  However, I am experiencing huge differences in calculation time when applying the two methods to recalculate a geometry field.

In the examples below, the point_geoms.point_within field is a geometry type field of the same type and SRID as "POINTS".geom

For example, this WHERE version runs almost instantly on the subset of ~5k records:

```
UPDATE "POINTS"
SET geom = point_geoms.point_within
FROM point_geoms
WHERE "POINTS"."POINT_ID" = point_geoms.point_id
```

While this INNER JOIN version will just keep spinning on and on, even when asked to only calculate a single row:

```
UPDATE "POINTS"
SET geom = p.point_within
FROM "POINTS" s
INNER JOIN point_geoms p
ON s."POINT_ID" = p.point_id
```

When I SELECT based on the very same INNER JOIN, it returns all ~5k records in the subset rather quickly.. which confuses me more as to why the INNER JOIN update is just spinning on and on.  When I EXPLAIN the select version, it looks like its only scanning the ~5k rows in the point_geoms table, however when updating it looks like it wants to scan all ~1M+ in the "POINTS" table.

Any thoughts / explanations would be greatly appreciated.  Perhaps I've just done something silly here.  Either way, would really like to understand whats going on.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way `UPDATE` works, the `INNER JOIN` version includes an unrestricted self-join between `"POINTS"` and its alias `s`, so there are many(!) more row updates. Worse, there are multiple output rows per target row to be updated, and so, were you to wait until the `UPDATE` completed, you'd get an indeterminate result.

`UPDATE`'s `FROM` clause isn't quite the same as that for a `SELECT` query, since the `UPDATE`'s target table (`"POINTS"`) is included without an explicit mention. See [the PostgreSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-update.html), which say:

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.
>
> Because of this indeterminacy, referencing other tables only within sub-selects is safer, though often harder to read and slower than using a join.

When the second query introduces the `FROM "POINTS" s` line, it effectively creates a `CROSS JOIN` from `"POINTS"` onto itself. Notice how the `EXPLAIN` output includes 2 sequence scans: one for `"POINTS"`, and another for its alias `"POINTS" s`:

```
postgres=# EXPLAIN UPDATE "POINTS"
SET geom = p.point_within
FROM "POINTS" s
INNER JOIN point_geoms p
ON s."POINT_ID" = p.point_id;
                                           QUERY PLAN                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on "POINTS"  (cost=140.50..62539765.00 rows=5000000000 width=28)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=140.50..62539765.00 rows=5000000000 width=28)
         ->  Seq Scan on "POINTS"  (cost=0.00..15406.00 rows=1000000 width=10)
                                    ... snip ...
                     ->  Seq Scan on "POINTS" s  (cost=0.00..15406.00 rows=1000000 width=10)
```

The number of output rows for this update is 5,000,000,000, and the updated values will, if the update ever finishes, be indeterminate i.e. garbage.

The other version does something entirely different, and only produces 5,000 output rows in
the process. Not only is it far quicker, it's likely to be what was intended.

As far as I know, it's not possible to intuitively use the `INNER JOIN` syntax when making an `UPDATE`. I hope that helps you understand what's going on.